# Where is Orochimaru?

Tags: naruto

Why isn't Orochimaru releasing the Edo Tensei seal of Hashirama?

Wouldn't that be helpful, as Madara would no longer be able to use his Senjutsu chakra?

Answer (score 1):

Madara has obtained the cells of Hashirama and has them infused into his body, irrespective of what happens to Edo tensei hashirama it will not affect anything with respect to Madara because he has been revived using the [rinne tensei](http://de.narutopedia.eu/wiki/Ged%C5%8D%3a_Rinne_Tensei_no_Jutsu) technique of six paths.

In short madara has both powers of Senju and Uciha and on top of that he is completely by himself (unlike being under Kabuto's control briefly when he was revived).

Comment: As i perceive it, madara is absorbing hashirama's chakra through those chakra rods thats been impaled on hashirama so without hashirama, madara wont have access to his senjutsu chakra.

Comment: we still dont know if thats the only he can get senjutsu chakra, Madara is a super genius with techniques i won't be surprised if he can absorb senjutsu like naruto/hashirama.

Answer (score 0):

> Where is Orochimaru?

He is currently with the Kages helping them heal.

> Why isn't he releasing the seal on Hashirama?

When Orochimaru first used Edo Tensei on Hashirama, Tobirama, Sarutobi, and Minato, Hashirama was already not bound to Orochimaru's control. The two contributing factors to this is that Hashirama is very strong and that Zetsu bodies were made of Hashirama cells. Thus releasing the restraint would not matter anyways.

Needless to say, I am pretty sure Orochimaru already released the seal as the rest of the Edo Tensei Hokage's are able to fight against Obito freely. Since Orochimaru is supporting the Shinobi Alliance, there would be no reason for him to keep them restrained.